# You cannot access this page directly - HybridAuth Social Login

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, hybridauth

I am using [**HybridAuth**](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth) social plugin in my website to login from facebook and other websites,

everything is working fine, but when I checked on other computers, there is an error:

> You cannot access this page directly

and I noticed that the error comes when the browser use `WWW` in the address bar, the browser on same computer eg: opera not using the `www` so there is no error on those browser.

Please help me how can I fix this error so login can be done from any browser.

Comment: set your base_url properly like `"base_url" => "http://sample.com/hybridauth/"`,  it may cause this error

Comment: This came up after changing how i handle sessions. Started using Zebra Sessions and this started. Disabling Zebra Session makes it work. But sadly I need/want to keep Zebra Session as well as needing this! So I would check if anything changed on how you handle/store sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasen is because Facebook callback in different php-session and cant access config info from caller session.
Look at Endpoint.php
if ( ! $storage->config( "CONFIG" ) ) ...
The rason was because I use in my site with 127.0.0.1 but return_uri was with localhost because of Facebook restrictions.
PHP builds different sessions in this case.

Comment: This answer seems to be what I'm looking for, but doesn't appear to detail the solution clearly enough. Can you confirm what needs to change in Endpoint.php? Thanks

Comment: yes - having a consistent uri in the config, ie. using http : // www . SITE . com, in all the necessary locations solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

adding "www." to the URL resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After adding this on top of my controller it started working

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    @session_id($_COOKIE['CAKEPHP']);
    @session_start();
    @session_name('CAKEPHP');
}
```

Read here
https://github.com/hybridauth/CakePHP-HybridAuth/pull/1

Comment: My website is not based on any standard MVC plugin. But we have similar structure . I was trying to write a plugin to connect with the facebook using Hybrid . But getting the same "You cannot access this page directly" error . Can you help how I can use your answer in my website ??. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750936/facebook-login-using-hybridauth-showing-error-you-cannot-access-this-page-direct  its the link to my question

Answer (score 0):

Those who are facing error message
"You cannot access this page directly."

Try after adding `@session_start();` statement at the top of your files.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related by using a custom session handler which is set by `session_set_save_handler()`.
I resolved this issue by adding our own custom session handler at the top of `hybridauth/index.php` (located in the same dir as `config.php` and `live.php`).
This forces Hybrid Auth to use your custom session handler.